# Assess if occurences of a binary variale is different from $\alpha \cdot 100 \%$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, significant-figures

I have a binary variable, $X_t$, which takes values $1$ or $0$. A value of $1$ indicates that an event happend at time $t$.

I would like to statistically test whether we can say that the event happens $\alpha \cdot 100 \%$ of the time. This is somewhat similar to the Kupiec test from the theory in Value-at-Risk backtesting, but my setting is a lot less specified and relies on basically no assumptions.

As an example, consider the following setup:
We have an observed vector of $X_t$: $X=[X_1, X_2, \dots, X_T]$. We want to know whether the event that $X_t = 1$ happens 5% of the time. If $T=1000$ and $sum(X)=62$, we could be compelled to decline the 5% hypothisis, since $62 \neq 50$. However, I want a test that takes statistical insecurity and potential finite sample properties into account.

I have considered some t-test-like approach, but I am unsure about the disitrbutional properties, and how to estimate the standard deviation in the denominator.

Additonally, I would like to test whether the occurence of the events is independent. Essentially, I would like to know whether an event happening at time $t$ affects the probability of an event happning at time $t+1$. For this, I have considered a simple autoregressive model, but I am unsure about this, as I have not seen anyone do this before.

**Anwsers to one of both questiosn are more than welcome!**

Comment: Your example is not how confidence intervals work.  If the success probability was $p=.05$  then, out of $1000$ observations, the probability of getting at most $61$ successes would be about $.949$, so getting more than $61$ has probability slightly greater than $5\%$.  Now, if your confidence level was $5\%$, unrelated to the success probability, you could (barely) reject the null hypothesis.  That computation takes into account the sample size, of course.

Comment: Testing independence can be tricky, since "dependence" can take on many forms.  A typical thing is to check auto-correlation.  See if your times series is connected to a shifter one (more simply, give $x_t$, does $x_{t+1}$ still satisfy the general statistics?).  Plot the data to try to detect patterns visually.  Some patterns are obvious, some are more subtle.  And small samples will often present unreal patterns.

Comment: @lulu: regarding your first comment - how do you calculate the probabilities? I guess you make some kind of disitrbutional assumption? I am looking for a method that does rely on too many assumptions - the fewer the better, since the event-process may have both heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation.

Regadring your second comment - Please elaborate on the this part: "See if your times series is connected to a shifter one (more simply, give $x_t$, does $x_{t+1}$ still satisfy the general statistics?)."

Comment: The null hypothesis, for a fixed success probability $p$, would, presumably, be the process was a simple binomial process.  Independent events.  $p$ would be computed, or estimated, either from some model you had or from the data (though if you compute it from the data, then you can't use it to test the hypothesis).

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) is a discussion of auto-correlation.

Comment: Should say:  it's always good to think about modeling the data.  If you have no idea at all what patterns might be present, you'll want to try a lot of hypotheses and such.  If you have some theory about what the data ought to look like, you can try to test that theory.  Statistics can be more art than science, especially if it's hard to acquire data.  Testing is certainly simpler in cases where it's easy to generate huge sample pools.